# Libgdx game crash after adding bullet physics

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to add bullet physics to my game in libgdx but , I'm using the Aide application for android,  so I downloaded the jar file and added it to libs in my libgdx project then I added the (.So ) file to my libs in the android project and exported it in class path  ، now I can import the bullet physics in my game and use it's methods,  but when I open my game it give me this log and crash my app

```
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 250255
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.mycompany.mygame15, PID: 24375
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx-bullet' for target: Linux, 32-bit
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:116)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.Bullet.init(Bullet.java:63)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.Bullet.init(Bullet.java:52)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.Bullet.init(Bullet.java:44)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.mygame15.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:60)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1586)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1299)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.mycompany.mygame15-2/lib/arm/libgdx-bullet.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:112)
01-05 20:09:37.145 24375 24410 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 7 more
```

My progurad file

```
-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

This some photo to make it easy to ubderstand

[image]

So what is the problem and how can I solve it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file code, especially the dependencies section

Comment: @GadWissberg There is no build.gradle  file but I there are proguard file (I edited it to question now)  , I searched in my project to find build. Grade but I didn't find it

Comment: How did you create your project? I strongly recommend you to create and manage your project using Gradle (or Maven) - You can generate using the setup app which provides you a well-defined libGDX project:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html
In the setup app, you can choose the option to include the gdx-bullet extension